# trigger a click event if confirmation message

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        alert("unload");
        if (closeIt())
            $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").trigger('click');

    });
    function closeIt() {
        var ans = confirm("save current layout ?");
        if (ans) return true;

    }
});
</script> 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveState_Click" style="display:none;" />
```

the new problem is that the confirm message is displayed twice on firefox and non of chrome

Comment: have you cheked if actually the confirm is setup correctly try putting like alert to see if it firing

Comment: instead `OnClick` modify `OnClientClick` in `button` property.

Comment: if the confirm message is confirmed the btnSaveState_Click is fired but he's executing the confirm message twice and i can't find the issue and 'Krunal' i can't use onClientClick because i want to execute a server side function

Comment: my question is edited please check

Answer (score 1):

All the `beforeunload` handler is really supposed to do is return a string, which the browser then displays in an "are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave" dialog. If the user clicks OK, whatever navigation was about to happen occurs; if they click Cancel, it doesn't. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907.aspx) for more detail.

The usual thing to do here would be to display a message (by returning a string, not calling `confirm` yourself) along this lines of "You're about to lose the changes you've made to the current layout; are you sure you want to leave?" and then let the user *themselves* click Cancel and then Save, or OK if they don't care.

You're having issues, I expect, because you're trying to perform a postback in the handler, and the postback *itself* would cause an unload. I wouldn't be surprised if the browser deliberately stops this kind of behaviour in the handler, because malicious sites could use it to stop you leaving.

As per your update: only some browsers even *allow* `beforeunoad` behaviour. By the looks of it, Firefox does, so you get two dialogs - your `confirm` and then the browser default one. And by the looks of it, Chrome doesn't, so your event never gets called. (Or maybe Chrome just ignores the event if it does something unexpected, like post back.)

Comment: than you mean i should not use a confirm message ?

Comment: No, don't use a confirm - use something like `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You're about to lose the changes you've made to the current layout; are you sure you want to leave?"; };` and the _browser_ will display that string in its own confirmation dialog.

Comment: ok but then how can i trigger my server side click event of Button1 ? if the user click on OK

Comment: If the user click on OK, they've decided not to save their changes. If they click Cancel, they'll have a chance to save their changes manually, and the message you use should make that obvious.

Comment: but like u see the save button has the display:none; so it's not visible on my page so the user can't save it's change manually for that reason i'm triggering it's click event

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that, sorry. I don't think there's a way you can do this if the user can't even see the save button.

Comment: than i guess i should find another way to do this maybe using a tooltip or something other than just a confirmation box

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnSaveState_Click"  onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
```

Alternatively you can look at the ASP.Net Ajax `<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>`

Comment: Weird, this should work work fine. Did you try it exactly with the `btnSaveState_Click` in the code behind?

Comment: What other controls do you have on the page? Do you have validators?

Comment: my browser is executing the confirm message twice like when i click ok the first time a second confirm message appear

Comment: This code causes a confirm to appear when you click the button, before allowing the postback. It won't help trigger the postback on page-unload at all.